# How does Rails fit in Client Rich web applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Ruby on Rails and am trying to understand its usage beyond the simple blog examples.

1. It appears that Rails makes it easy to interact with forms and receive/persist objects to the database.  I get this for "twitter' or "blog" type applications.  But what about more real world type examples?  Lets say we build a site that has a home page full of mostly static information with sign-in/sign-up (w/ Devise and OmniAuth).

   a.  Do I need a "home" controller?
   b.  For that matter, do I need a controller that corresponds with every type of webpage on the site (assuming the page is not 100% static, in which case it would be in the /public)?
2. What if after you log-in the user is taken to a feature rich page that uses a graph, a data table, and a map?  Maybe those 3 things require data from 3 different models.  How is this to be done?  I suppose in this case there would be lot of client side logic (like Kendo UI or Jquery).  So I imagine that the rails app would basically just become a json API?  If a page is going to have a lot of client side whiz-bang... is rails the right back end?

sorry for the stupid questions.. I am without a rails mentor.

Comment: Short answer: yes.  All of the products developed by 37 Signals (Basecamp, Campfire, others) are written in Rails and are brilliant, complex and deep.  Rails is an incredibly powerful and flexible framework for writing fully dynamic modern web applications ... including all of the front-end client side behaviors.  I have been writing in Rails since 2007, and it is beyond unbelievably great for front and back end.  But I digress, because the real answer is "this is really a question of opinion" so doesn't really satisfy the criteria for a SO question.  Try Quora for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Rails is a good framework to start off from, but it is no replacement for the more fancy stuff you may want to do on the front end. Also, read up on model associations.

Answer (score 1):

1. a)  You do not need a 'home' controller.  However, you should have some controller to handle the 'root' path as a landing-page/dashboard and a 'home' controller handles this nicely.

   b)  You will need a controller to handle every conceptual category or resource (as in REST), but not necessarily a single controller for every page.  For instance, all 'help' pages can be handled by a single controller.
2. The underlying data for a graph can be built along with the initial page, or more commonly via ajax, from a controller action.  The controller action would be responsible for collecting and returning the appropriate data.  You can then use a client side api (google charts for instance) to build the visual graph, or you can do it server side with a helper module and return the needed image or HTML/JS/CSS to represent the graph.

> If a page is going to have a lot of client side whiz-bang... is rails the right back end?

This question can get you into trouble on SO :)

However, an argument can be made that it's as good as any other framework for encapsulating a client-side 'whiz-bang' library.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working in a Rails Single Page web application with Form based Administration area and Single Page Application for the general user front end.

For the Single Page Application Rails provides the RESTful API (JSON) to provide the data, where the presentation logic is implemented using Javascript & organized in closer to MVC pattern using Backbone.js.

For your question
1)

a) For the authentication using Devise you might need a controller to interpret the log-in request but for the subsequent requests you can decide what are your basic routes and controller mapping.

b) No! you don't need individual controllers for each webpage on the site. You can use the same controller and render a different view based on the request method and parameters.

2)
If you are fetching the data for each graph, data table and map in different models one way is to implement a controller which queries the data from each model and prepares in a suitable way for each UI element. For that the easiest way is to render the view in JSON so that it is easy to bind data for the UI components.

If you want to render the JSON in a flexible way https://github.com/nesquena/rabl would be a good option.

Currently I'm working in a project (Almost two years old) with Rails & still the RESTful JSON API evolves without significant challenges.

Answer (score 1):

> If a page is going to have a lot of client side whiz-bang... is rails the right back end?

Rails is fine as your back end for apps with client-heavy code. At some point you're (probably) going to need to do some basic user management and authentication, as well as getting and sending some sort of persistent data so Rails isn't "wrong", per se. One could argue that a lighter framework such as [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) if you're going to use Ruby, or something like [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) (Python) or the Javascript stack of [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) + [express](http://expressjs.com) would be a better fit if you truly are just going to create a RESTful API + some landing pages, but Rails does this perfectly fine as well, and has a lot of other functionality that will be available for you to grow into if the time ever comes.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the great answers above.

I actually just came across a video that does a fantastic job of answering my question.  I post it here for those who those who come along and may be curious:

http://ontwik.com/ruby/building-rails-apps-for-the-rich-client/